# Не передаётся двумерный массив в C

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели, память

```
int detForDIM3(int** matrix) { // function for calculating determinant of matrix 3 by 3)

    //
}

Plane* makePlane(Point *x, Point *y, Point *z) { 

    int matrix[DIM][DIM];

    ***

    plane->vals[colFor1] = detForDIM3(&matrix);
```

Я хочу передать в функцию матрицу 3 на 3 ( DIM*DIM ). Создаю её в программе, передаю, но получает detForDIM3 только указатель на ничто. Как это исправить
Пробовал передавать:
int matrix[][DIM] - не помогло
int **matrix - не помогло

detForDIM3(matrix) - не помогло
detForDIM3(&matrix) - не помогло

Вот, собственно скриншот большего куска кода с тем, что передаётся:
[image: Скриншот того, что передаётся в функцию]
При matrix[][DIM] передаётся только первая строка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это совершенно разные типы. Двумерный массив - это, грубо говоря, один блок памяти, разделенный на строки. А `int**` - это одномерный массив указателей на одномерные же массивы.

Comment: Harry, то есть только путём динамического выделения памяти так можно передавать эту матрицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// matrixp - указатель на матрицу
void f(int (*matrixp)[DIM][DIM]){
  ...
  (*matrixp)[i][j] - значения
}

void g(void) {
   int matrix[DIM][DIM];
   f(&matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```c
#define DIM 3

inline int getValue(int* martix, int x, int y) {
    return martix[DIM * y + x];
}

int main() {
    int matrix[DIM][DIM]; 

    int cell21 = getValue((int*)matrix, 2, 1);
}
```

В памяти ваш массив (при обнулении его значений) выглядит так:

```
00 00 00  00 00 00  00 00 00
```

При выделении памяти в стэке для стэка эти две строчки эквивалентны:

```c
int a[3][3];
```

```c
int a[9];
```

Поэтому нужно передавать как `int*`. Если размер массива динамический, нужно передавать и его кол-во строк и/или кол-во столбцов. Чтобы получить значение массива ячейки используется вот такая формула:

```c
a[columnCount * y + x];
```

Взгляните на рисунок с байтами, на эту формулу и попытайтесь найти значение matrix[2][1], если вы хотите точно понять, как это работает.

---

Вот формула чтоб найти `a[z][y][x]` при `a[sizeZ][sizeY][sizeX]`:

```c
int* _a = (int*)a;

_a[(sizeX * sizeY) * z + sizeX * y + x]; // пропускаем "таблицу" ((sizeX * sizeY) * z)
                                         // затем пропускаем строку (sizeX * y)
                                         // затем добавляем смещение (x)
```

Заметьте, на первую размерность всем всегда всё равно)

Answer (score 1):

Жаль, что у вас С, а не С++... Там проще.

Смотрите, когда компилятор видит матрицу типа `int a[M][N]`, то он генерирует обращение к `a[i][j]` как к `*((int*)a + i*M + j)` - и ему обязательно нужно знать это значение `M`. Поэтому передавать нужно как минимум как

```
.... func(int a[][M],...)
```

где `M` - значение времени компиляции. Если у вас все матрицы с одинаковым количеством столбцов - можно так.

Но если вы не привязаны к конкретно матрице, например, какой-то библиотекой - то проще реализовать матрицу именно как `int**` и передавать как указатель. Для этого ее надо один раз создать - типа,

```
int ** a = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    a[i] = malloc(M*sizeof(int));
```

и тогда работать с `a`, как с матрицей. Просто теперь компилятор будет выполнять обращение иначе - как

```
*(*(a+i)+j)
```

и ему уже не нужно знать размерность матрицы. Такую матрицу вы просто передаете как `int**` (сопровождая размерами при необходимости для себя, а не для компилятора).

Примерно так.

Ну, а тут выбирайте, что для вашей ситуации подходит больше...